# ListBox databinding and immutability

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm having some problems with `ListBox` databinding and immutability. I have a model that provides a `List` of some elements and a ViewModel that takes these elements and puts them to an `ObservableCollection` which is bound to the `ListBox`.

The elements, however, are not mutable so when they change - which happens when user changes `ListBox`'s selection or in a few other scenarios - the model fires up an event and the ViewModel retrieves a new `List` of new elements instances and repopulates the `ObservableCollection`.

This approach works quite well - despite being obviously not optimal - when user interacts with the `ListBox` via mouse (clicking) but fails horribly when using keyboard (tab to focus current element and then using mouse arrows or further tabbing). For some reason the `ActiveSchema` gets always reset to the first element of the `Schemas`[*].

The `ActiveSchema` setter gets called for the schema user switched to, then for null, and finally for the first value again. For some reason the two last events don't happen when invoked via mouse.

PS: Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/petrroll/PowerSwitcher)

PPS: I know I should probably rework the model so it exposes `ObservableCollection` that mutates but there're reasons why trashing everything and creating it from scratch is just a bit more reliable.

```
//ListBox's Items source is bound to:
public ObservableCollection<IPowerSchema> Schemas { get; private set; }

//ListBox's Selected item is bound to:
public IPowerSchema ActiveSchema
{
    get { return Schemas.FirstOrDefault(sch => sch.IsActive); }
    set { if (value != null) { pwrManager.SetPowerSchema(value); } }
}

//When model changes:
private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == nameof(IPowerManager.PowerSchemas))
    {
        updateCurrentSchemas();
    }
}

private void updateCurrentSchemas()
{
    Schemas.Clear();

    var currSchemas = pwrManager.PowerSchemas;
    currSchemas.ForEach(sch => Schemas.Add(sch));

    RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(ActiveSchema));
}
```

Comment: Well for "For some reason the ActiveSchema gets always reset to the first element of the Schemas[*]." In getter you are getting the first (active) element of new list. Maybe you need to change this,